# SKU and Price on product that have multiple attributes

Tags: database-design, normalization

Currently, my Inventory system is writing products data like this:

1. T-Shirt Gildan -> blue, L, short -> stock: 140 -> price: $40
2. T-Shirt Gildan -> blue, XL, short -> stock: 0 -> price: $45
3. T-Shirt RedMango -> blue, L, short -> stock : 100 -> price: $30
4. T-Shirt RedMango -> red, L, short -> stock : 140 -> price: $30
5. T-Shirt RedMango -> red, L, long -> stock : 100 -> price: $35

Basically, I want to create a website like products catalog. e.g user flow:

1. User choose a T-Shirt Gildan product (options: T-Shirt Gildan or T-Shirt RedMango)
2. User choose blue color: (option: only blue)
3. User choose XL size: (options: L or XL, inform the user if XL size is out of stock)

To achieve that flow, I'm try to normalize above data. Then I'm to split to some tables. Here's my current work.

Table **product**

```
---------------------
id | name
---------------------
1  | T-Shirt Gildan
2  | T-Shirt RedMango
```

Table **attr**

```
------------
id | name
------------
1  | color
2  | size
3  | sleeve
```

Table **attr_value**

```
---------------------------------------
id | attr_variant_id | attr_id | value
---------------------------------------
1  |        1        |    1    | blue
2  |        1        |    2    | L
3  |        1        |    3    | short 
4  |        2        |    1    | blue
5  |        2        |    2    | XL
6  |        2        |    3    | short
```

Table **attr_variant**

```
------------------------------------------------
id | product_id |       sku      | price | stock
------------------------------------------------
1  |     1      |  #Blue#L#Short | $40   | 140
2  |     1      | #Blue#XL#Short | $45   | 0
```

Is that tables enough for my user flow?

Comment: Your `attr_variant.sku` makes the tables `attr` and `attr_value` excess. And `attr_value.attr_id` seems to be wrong.

Comment: ```attr_value.attr_id``` has been fixed. Why tables ```attr``` and ```attr_value``` excess?

Comment: *Why tables `attr` and `attr_value` excess?* 1) Their values may be extracted from `sku` 2) Attributes are positionally-defined 3) The values in `attr` and `attr_value` may theoretically contradict with the same values in `sku` - and you cannot to build the constraint logic for this integrity check. PS. I have not said that these tables are excess, I have said that this structure of `sku` makes them excess.